# Facing a problem with my angular 10 app where http Interceptor is not working

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

Please i'm facing a problem with my angular app. Im not able to rewrite headers before sending a http request to the backend.

- My interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';

import { TokenStorageService } from '../_services/token-storage.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = this.token.getToken();
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken
      }
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

I add the provider in appComponent

`providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }]`

I also here import the HttpClientModule .

The app Module:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';


import { MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar/';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { DossiersComponent } from './dossiers/dossiers.component';
import { OuvertureComponent } from './dossiers/ouverture/ouverture.component';
import { ModificationComponent } from './dossiers/modification/modification.component';
import { VisualisationComponent } from './dossiers/visualisation/visualisation.component';
import { EmployeesComponent } from './employees/employees.component';
import { CreateEmpComponent } from './employees/create-emp/create-emp.component';
import { UpdateEmpComponent } from './employees/update-emp/update-emp.component';
import { DeleteEmpComponent } from './employees/delete-emp/delete-emp.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './user-profile/login/login.component';
import { DossierManagementComponent } from './dossier-management/dossier-management.component';
import { CodifierComponent } from './dossiers/visualisation/codifier/codifier.component';
import { NoCommaPipe } from './shared-core/no-comma.pipe';
import { ServiceCrudComponent } from './dossiers/service-crud/service-crud.component';
import { PilotageComponent } from './dossiers/pilotage/pilotage.component';
import { FinalisationDossierComponent } from './dossiers/finalisation-dossier/finalisation-dossier.component';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './_helpers/auth.interceptor';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ChartsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    DossiersComponent,
    OuvertureComponent,
    ModificationComponent,
    VisualisationComponent,
    EmployeesComponent,
    CreateEmpComponent,
    UpdateEmpComponent,
    DeleteEmpComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DossierManagementComponent,
    CodifierComponent,
    NoCommaPipe,
    ServiceCrudComponent,
    PilotageComponent,
    FinalisationDossierComponent

  ],
  providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The app routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './user-profile/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent

  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
      }]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard'
  }
];
//
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The App component is empty

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

I have a Layout module for the app

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AdminLayoutRoutes } from './admin-layout.routing';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from '../../user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { TableListComponent } from '../../table-list/table-list.component';
import { TypographyComponent } from '../../typography/typography.component';
import { IconsComponent } from '../../icons/icons.component';
import { MapsComponent } from '../../maps/maps.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from '../../notifications/notifications.component';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '../../upgrade/upgrade.component';
import { ClientelleComponent } from '../../clientelle/clientelle.component';
import { UpdateComponent } from '../../clientelle/update/update.component';
import { CreateComponent } from '../../clientelle/create/create.component';
import { DeleteComponent } from '../../clientelle/delete/delete.component';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar/';
import { ViewComponent } from '../../clientelle/view/view.component';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    A11yModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ChartsModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    NgbModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    TableListComponent,
    UpgradeComponent,
    TypographyComponent,
    IconsComponent,
    MapsComponent,
    ClientelleComponent,
    UpdateComponent,
    CreateComponent,
    ViewComponent,
    DeleteComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
  ]
})

export class AdminLayoutModule { }
```

His routing module

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from '../../user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { TableListComponent } from '../../table-list/table-list.component';
import { TypographyComponent } from '../../typography/typography.component';
import { IconsComponent } from '../../icons/icons.component';
import { MapsComponent } from '../../maps/maps.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from '../../notifications/notifications.component';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '../../upgrade/upgrade.component';
import { ClientelleComponent } from '../../clientelle/clientelle.component';
import { UpdateComponent } from '../../clientelle/update/update.component';
import { CreateComponent } from '../../clientelle/create/create.component';
import { ViewComponent } from '../../clientelle/view/view.component';
import { DossiersComponent } from '../../dossiers/dossiers.component';
import { OuvertureComponent } from '../../dossiers/ouverture/ouverture.component';
import { VisualisationComponent } from '../../dossiers/visualisation/visualisation.component';
import { ModificationComponent } from '../../dossiers/modification/modification.component';
import { EmployeesComponent } from '../../employees/employees.component';
import { CreateEmpComponent } from '../../employees/create-emp/create-emp.component';
import { UpdateEmpComponent } from '../../employees/update-emp/update-emp.component';
import { DossierManagementComponent } from '../../dossier-management/dossier-management.component';
import { DossierListGuard } from '../../_helpers/guards/dossier-list.guard';
import { DossierCreerGuard } from '../../_helpers/guards/dossier-creer.guard';
import { DossierVisualiserGuard } from '../../_helpers/guards/dossier-visualiser.guard';
import { DossierAttribuerGuard } from '../../_helpers/guards/dossier-attribuer.guard';
import { EmployerGererGuard } from '../../_helpers/guards/employer-gerer.guard';
import { ClientGererGuard } from '../../_helpers/guards/client-gerer.guard';
import { ServiceCrudComponent } from '../../dossiers/service-crud/service-crud.component';
import { PilotageComponent } from '../../dossiers/pilotage/pilotage.component';
import { FinalisationDossierComponent } from '../../dossiers/finalisation-dossier/finalisation-dossier.component';

export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent },
  { path: 'table-list', component: TableListComponent },
  { path: 'typography', component: TypographyComponent },
  { path: 'icons', component: IconsComponent },
  { path: 'maps', component: MapsComponent },
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent },
  { path: 'clientelle', canActivate: [ClientGererGuard], component: ClientelleComponent },
  { path: 'client/UpdateClient/:id', canActivate: [ClientGererGuard], component: UpdateComponent },
  { path: 'client/ViewClient/:id', canActivate: [ClientGererGuard], component: ViewComponent },
  { path: 'NewClient', canActivate: [ClientGererGuard], component: CreateComponent },
  { path: 'dossiers', canActivate: [DossierCreerGuard], component: DossiersComponent },
  { path: 'services', canActivate: [DossierCreerGuard], component: ServiceCrudComponent },
  { path: 'pilotage/:idDossier', canActivate: [DossierCreerGuard], component: PilotageComponent },
  { path: 'finalisation/:idDossier', canActivate: [DossierCreerGuard], component: FinalisationDossierComponent },
  { path: 'dossier/ouverture/:idClient', canActivate: [DossierCreerGuard], component: OuvertureComponent },
  { path: 'dossier/visualiser/:idDossier', canActivate: [DossierVisualiserGuard], component: VisualisationComponent },
  { path: 'dossier/modifier/:idDossier', canActivate: [DossierCreerGuard], component: ModificationComponent },
  { path: 'Employes', canActivate: [EmployerGererGuard], component: EmployeesComponent },
  { path: 'NewEmployee', canActivate: [EmployerGererGuard], component: CreateEmpComponent },
  { path: 'dossier/GererDossier', canActivate: [DossierAttribuerGuard], component: DossierManagementComponent },
  { path: 'modifierEmployee/:idEmp', canActivate: [EmployerGererGuard], component: UpdateEmpComponent },
  { path: 'upgrade', component: UpgradeComponent }

];
```

The Layout component

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy, PopStateEvent } from '@angular/common';

import { NavbarComponent } from '../../components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';
import { TokenStorageService } from '../../_services/token-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-layout',
  templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-layout.component.scss']
})
export class AdminLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  private _router: Subscription;
  private lastPoppedUrl: string;
  private yScrollStack: number[] = [];

  constructor(public location: Location, private router: Router, private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.tokenStorage.getToken()) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // alert(redirectionUrl);
        window.location.href = '/login';
      }, 500);

    }
    const isWindows = navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') > -1 ? true : false;

    if (isWindows && !document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.contains('sidebar-mini')) {
      // if we are on windows OS we activate the perfectScrollbar function

      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('perfect-scrollbar-on');
    } else {
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.remove('perfect-scrollbar-off');
    }
    const elemMainPanel = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.main-panel');
    const elemSidebar = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.sidebar .sidebar-wrapper');

    this.location.subscribe((ev: PopStateEvent) => {
      this.lastPoppedUrl = ev.url;
    });
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event.url != this.lastPoppedUrl)
          this.yScrollStack.push(window.scrollY);
      } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (event.url == this.lastPoppedUrl) {
          this.lastPoppedUrl = undefined;
          window.scrollTo(0, this.yScrollStack.pop());
        } else
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
    });
    this._router = this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
      elemMainPanel.scrollTop = 0;
      elemSidebar.scrollTop = 0;
    });
    if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 960px)`).matches && !this.isMac()) {
      let ps = new PerfectScrollbar(elemMainPanel);
      ps = new PerfectScrollbar(elemSidebar);
    }
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.runOnRouteChange();
  }
  isMaps(path) {
    var titlee = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path());
    titlee = titlee.slice(1);
    if (path == titlee) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  runOnRouteChange(): void {
    if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 960px)`).matches && !this.isMac()) {
      const elemMainPanel = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.main-panel');
      const ps = new PerfectScrollbar(elemMainPanel);
      ps.update();
    }
  }
  isMac(): boolean {
    let bool = false;
    if (navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') >= 0 || navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('IPAD') >= 0) {
      bool = true;
    }
    return bool;
  }

}
```

TokenStorage code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';
const USER_KEY = 'auth-user';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class TokenStorageService {

  constructor() { }

  signOut(): void {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }

  public saveToken(token: string): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
  }

  public getToken(): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
  }

  public saveUser(user): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  public getUser(): any {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY));
  }
}
```

Comment: You added the interceptor to the imports list in the app **module**, right? Not the app *component* as you state?

Comment: We need more details on your question. Does the code enter in the `intercept` function? Can you please add `TokenStorageService` code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i provide here more details.

Comment: Can you verify that the `intercept()` method is being called?

Comment: Hi @BizzyBob Yes i  verified that. It is effectively called.